# Using Concurrency::concurrent_queue together with std::unique_ptr

Tags: visual-studio-2010, concurrency-runtime, concurrent-queue

I want to use the Concurrency library of Visual Studio 2010 to pass actions between threads.
I have my class `SimpleAction` and pointers to it are stored in the `Concurrency::concurrent_queue`.

Using this definition, and 'consumption' logic it works:

```
typedef Concurrency::concurrent_queue<SimpleAction *> ActionQueue;

while (true)
   {
   SimpleAction *action = nullptr;
   while (m_queue.try_pop(action))
      {
      action->process();
      delete action;
      }
   Sleep(100);
   }
```

However, when I change this to an std::unique_ptr, like this:

```
typedef Concurrency::concurrent_queue<std::unique_ptr<SimpleAction>> ActionQueue;

while (true)
   {
   std::unique_ptr<SimpleAction> action;
   while (m_queue.try_pop(action))
      {
      action->process();
      }
   Sleep(100);
   }
```

The compiler gives the following error message:

> ```
> F:\DevStudio\Vs2010\VC\INCLUDE\concurrent_queue.h(366) : error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
>     with
>     [
>         _Ty=`anonymous-namespace'::SimpleAction
>     ]
> F:\DevStudio\Vs2010\VC\INCLUDE\memory(2347) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr'
>     with
>     [
>         _Ty=`anonymous-namespace'::SimpleAction
>     ]
> F:\DevStudio\Vs2010\VC\INCLUDE\concurrent_queue.h(365) : while compiling class template member function 'void Concurrency::concurrent_queue<_Ty>::_Copy_item(Concurrency::details::_Concurrent_queue_base_v4::_Page &,size_t,const void *)'
>     with
>     [
>         _Ty=std::unique_ptr<`anonymous-namespace'::SimpleAction>
>     ]
> test.cpp(138) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::concurrent_queue<_Ty>' being compiled
>     with
>     [
>         _Ty=std::unique_ptr<`anonymous-namespace'::SimpleAction>
>     ]
> ```

It seems the compiler does not like this construction in concurrent_queue:

```
/*override*/ virtual void _Copy_item( _Page& _Dst, size_t _Index, const void* _Src )
{
    new( &_Get_ref(_Dst,_Index) ) _Ty(*static_cast<const _Ty*>(_Src)); 
}
```

Which seems logical (we don't want an std::unique_ptr to be copied (it must be moved instead).

Questions:

- Is this a known problem/limitation/feature of the Concurrency/PPL library of Visual Studio 2010?
- Is this problem solved in Visual Studio 2012?
- Or am I doing something wrong?

thanks,
Patrick

Comment: I had the same question did it work for you ?

Comment: No I didn't find any solution (but I haven't looked much further I admit)

Comment: In my case it didn't like the redefinition of new for memory leak checks. I just included concurrent_queue.h before it.